# When adding array values in javascript, what is the difference between push and []?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had a question while using array in JavaScript.

I know two ways to add values ​​to an array.

first:

```
let arr = [];
arr.push(1);// arr[0] = 1;
```

second:

```
let arr = [];
arr['1'] = 1;// arr['1'] = 1;
```

I want to know exactly how this behavior is different.

Comment: Look up `sparse array`

Comment: ouch. thank you.! i`ll find and study right now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.push will push the element to the last position in the array. With this method, you cannot overrider the existing values. However using the brackets notation you can set the value at any index of the array like

```
arr[1] = 1;
arr[5] = 2;
```

Also note that `array` accepts indexes as keys which can be parsed as an integer. So assigning a value to an array like

```
arr["foo"] = 3
```

isn't quite the right approach,

Comment: Your last statement is wrong. Array's just like any objects, can only have strings or Symbols as their keys. Anything else is implicitly converted to a string. Arrays just treat integral numeric strings specially.

Comment: EG. `Object.keys(['foo'])[0] === '0'` and `Object.keys(['foo'])[0] !== 0`

Answer (score 2):

Array.prototype.push method of array is having some advantage over indexed.

- By using push your array will not have any chance of any empty index    value.Which is related to performne optimization.
- You can push in an object with call and apply method.ex:Array.prototype.push.call(obj,'value');
- No need to find out the position where you want to push the new element.
- Can merge two array with push method

Comment: "*Can merge two array with push method*" How? Did you mean with `arr1.push.apply(arr1,arr2)`?  Then it's the `apply`  method that does the magic.

Comment: you can push arr2 content into arr1 by simply doing push ex:arr1.push(arr2) or arr1.push.call(arr1,arr2) but to push it  index by index you shoud use apply.

Comment: That's what I feared... `arr1=[], arr2=[]; arr1.push(arr2);` at this moment arr1 will be `[[]]`. i.e you are not pushing arr2 **content**, but arr2 itself, as an Array.

Comment: You are absolutely correct but Array.push.apply(arr1,arr2) will merge arr2 content into arr1. ex:arr1=['raja'];arr2=['kaiido'];Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1,arr2).now arr1 will have the content of arr2 with a new reference.I mean changing arr2 content will not effect arr1

Answer (score -2):

The `arr.push(1)` syntax adds a value to your array. `arr['1'] = 1` is invalid syntax. You can try this out in the browser console.